# How do I get the value of a changing attribute from a php form?

Tags: php, mysql

I am pulling information to be displayed from my database and what id like to happen is when the user clicks on a selection, its takes them to a form that would be just for that selection. So i have one form and im trying to pull the name attribute whose value is set but $form_id which gets its value depending on the person chosen. on the top id get the attribute's value displayed in my url bar which i dont mind, but i cant seem to echo it out. After I am able to pull the value i will then place it back into the database. Please see code below. Thank you!

EDIT:
For further clarification, i am pulling a list of names and ID's from the database. I am also pulling just the ID a second time and assigning it to form_id. I display this information on a button because when you click that button it should take you to a form that will then ask you for information that will be added to the row that holds your form_id. My problem is that form_id isnt coming over as the variable but what its assigned to ex. if form id assumes the value of 7, as per the id it pulls from the database, a $_GET(['form_id']) no longer works because 7 is what is being sent over, not form_id

Before you submit form (click button):

```
<?php
while($pro_showcase = mysqli_fetch_assoc($pro_s))
{
    $form_id = $pro_showcase['performance_id'];
    echo "<div class=\"xs-col-4 col-sm-offset-2 separate\"><form 
        role=\"form\"action=\"judge-form.php\" method=\"get\"><button name=\"$form_id\"  
        type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-danger\">        <p>ID: ";
    echo implode("<br> ",$pro_showcase);

    echo "</p></button></form></div>";
}
?>
```

After submission, where it submits to:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['submit']))
{
    $n = $_GET["$form_id"];
    echo $n;
}
?>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please explain more.

Comment: Try to print the entire $_GET variable to see what you have there. Use `print_r($_GET)`. And what about sending the form_id in hidden input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the `$form_id` mixed up. The value in your HTML code will be replaced with whatever is in `$form_id` variable, but you won't have a `$form_id` array key in `$_GET` after you submit the form. This is because the **names** of the HTML form elements map to **keys** in `$_GET`. What you have done in your code is: map the **value** of `$form_id` variable (for example `7`) to a **key** in the `$_GET`.

You should instead use constant **name** for the HTML form elment, but with **value** of the `$form_id` variable:

```
<button name="form_id" value=\"$form_id\" type=\"submit\" class=\"btn btn-danger\">
```

Then you can capture the value like this:

```
$n = $_GET['form_id'];
```

(without `$` sign).

If you are confused with parsing variables into strings, you can use the [curly syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/pl/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex), which makes the string a lot more readable.

Comment: I can't vote you up because I don't have enough points but thank you so much it worked as you said.